# How to mock multiple components in camel unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I'm using the `CamelTestSupport` in camel version 2.13.1.

I'd like to do something like this to mock out two different components:

```
@Override
public String isMockEndpoints() {
    return "(activemq|exec)*";
}
```

I can't just mock everything with "*" because I was getting errors from the activiti framework I'm using, which relies on the `activiti` component.

Have any of you found a way to do something like this?

Comment: I don't use isMockEndpoints, so can't help you there, but I *do* mock endpoint uri's which you can do as "granularly" (is that a word?) as you like. E.g. a mocked uri might look like mock:<your-uri> etc. Then I have test and prod settings which denote the uri's with or without the "mock" in front.

Comment: I see what you are saying. With this particular suite I am attempting to mock existing routes for a more integration-style test.

Comment: I do something similar; for tests (run with e.g. junit, but not really unit tests, more like integration tests) I have a different context file (which includes my main context file but overrides a few things, loads a different properties file, etc.). The properties for test use mock uri's whereas the properties for prod don't. Unit test loads the appropriate settings and runs with mocks, etc. It requires your route to use a property for the <to> or <from> etc. uri's which is then set according to prod/test props. Just one way to do it, I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression, so its something a like:

```
 return "(activemq.*|exec.*)"
```

See bottom of this page 
http://camel.apache.org/intercept