# How to conditionally load a camel route based on a flag?

Tags: java, caching, apache-camel

I have an application using apache camel, activemq among other things. I also use camel-cache for caching objects. I am trying to run all my test classes in parallel to reduce the build time. This is the maven configuration I use

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.18.1</version>
     <configuration>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This creates a new camel context for each of the test class. This would run fine except for the trouble with the cache. we have a route which initializes the cache as shown below:

```
 <route id="xcache">
   <from uri="cache://xCache?maxElementsInMemory=1000&amp;overflowToDisk=true&amp;timeToLiveSeconds=300&amp;timeToIdleSeconds=200" />
   <log loggingLevel="INFO" logName="IFATMSTrace" message="X Cache configuration initialized." />
 </route>
```

Multiple camelContexts try to initialize cache with the same name 'xCache' and throw an exception. For various reasons, I cannot make each of the context to create its own cache. To solve this problem, I want to disable caching completely during testing so that the tests can pass

To achieve this, I tried using the autoStartup attribute to load the cache route manually

```
<route id="xcache" autoStartup="false">
  .....
</route>
```

and then defined a flag in a config file which will be false in the testing context, then used the controlbus component to start it manually.

```
 <route id="startDormantRoutes">
        <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=2000" />
        <setProperty propertyName="isCacheEnabled">
            <simple>${bean:myUtils?method=isCacheEnabled}</simple>
        </setProperty>
        <log loggingLevel="DEBUG" logName="IFATMSTrace" message="Cache Enabled : ${property.isCacheEnabled}" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${property.isCacheEnabled} == "true"</simple>
                <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=xcache&amp;action=start" />
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

This should have solved my problem but what happens is during the shutting down of the camelcontext, I get a NullPointerException

```
pool-1-thread-16] SpringCamelContext WARN  Error occurred while shutting down service: org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService@63442e11. This exception will be ignored.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheConsumer.doStop(CacheConsumer.java:47)[camel-cache-2.12.0.redhat-610379.jar:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.stop(ServiceSupport.java:102)[camel-core-2.12.0.redhat-610379.jar:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
```

and the testcases further all fail with the exception that xCache is already defined or some such thing.

On further investigation, I found out that even though the xcache route is not loaded at all, some child services related to the route are loaded

```
[               pool-1-thread-1] SpringCamelContext             DEBUG Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver@4de49608 to resolve component with name: cache
[               pool-1-thread-1] DefaultComponentResolver       DEBUG Found component: cache in registry: null
[               pool-1-thread-1] DefaultComponentResolver       DEBUG Found component: cache via type: org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheComponent via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/cache
[               pool-1-thread-1] DefaultManagementAgent         DEBUG Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=myAdapterCamelContext,type=components,name="cache"
[               pool-1-thread-1] DefaultComponent               DEBUG Creating endpoint uri=[cache://xCache], path=[xCache]
[               pool-1-thread-1] SpringCamelContext             DEBUG cache://xCache converted to endpoint: Endpoint[cache://xCache] by component: org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheComponent@7cc8ff30
[               pool-1-thread-1] DefaultManagementAgent         DEBUG Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=myAdapterCamelContext,type=endpoints,name="cache://xCache"
[               pool-1-thread-1] DefaultChannel                 DEBUG Initialize channel for target: 'To[cache://xCache]'
```

Comment: Is it easy for you to paretermize the route endpoint as a property, e.g. `<from uri="${xcache.route}">` and for your test case set it it `stub:foo` and the live version `cache://xCache....`. This as I understand should prevent the `cache:` endpoint from being initialized.

Comment: I guess I could do it, but it feels more like a hack. Isn't there a simple way to conditionally add a route where it doesn't do any initialization if it is not started

Comment: Well the problem is that camel scans all the endpoints and initializes any of the components it finds. In my experience, I either needed to parameterize the component to "hide" it, alternatively in your tests to register a custom "mock" version of the component.

Comment: So, in my tests can I mock out the cache component so that the "real" cache component is not initialized at all? Could you point to some resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer:

The problem is that camel scans all the endpoints and initializes any of the components it finds.

In my experience, if you need to stop a component from initializing (perhaps it does some heavy initialization, or takes up a port, or for whatever reason), I either needed to:

1. parameterize the component endpoint to "hide" the component from camel in tests.
2. alternatively, in your tests, register a custom "mock" version of the component.
3. or lastly you could consider having entirely different contexts, and just start the ones you need.

Maybe there is an easier way to do this but this was my experience.

**Edit**: Claus Ibsen has suggested an easy way to mock components, why don't you try this:

[How to mock multiple components in camel unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458180/how-to-mock-multiple-components-in-camel-unit-test)